# Is there any OnClick event of Telerik RadGrid Command Item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

When I add `CommandItemDisplay="Top"` in my Telrik RadGrid `MasterTableView`, I get 1 button `AddNewRecordButton` and 1 LinkButton `InitInsertButton`.

Now, I would like to do some code on their `onclick` event i.e., Button/LinkButton enable and disable based on some condition.

**All I need to do is:**
There is a RadComboBox (outside of RadGrid) in my Web page and a RadGrid.

When first time page loads, and user forgets to Select Item from RadComboBox
and clicks on "Add New" button of RadGrid
then this button should disable at that time and an alert should come (Select item from ComboBox first)

Now, when user select the item from RadComboBox, 
and then click on "Add New" button of RadGrid
then it should perform "add" functionality   //---this part is done

Below code (replied by Roman) is working fine to disable the "Add New" button and show alert.

But how to create this requirement using this code? Where to put this line of code so that it should work as per need. Please guide.
Please note that I am very new in Telerik controls so if I ask something very basic please forgive and try to guide me in a simple way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RadGrid_ItemCreated()` event and `Attributes.Add()` method:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridCommandItem)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("AddNewRecordButton");
        btn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "test()");

        LinkButton linkBtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
        linkBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "test()");
    }
}
```

And then add your function to your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        alert("test message");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Please check my posted question (from "All I need to do") I made an edit in it and explained what I really want to do. Your code is working but I am unable to implement my requirement using your code. Please guide me.

Comment: The only problem you've got is to alert a message when nothing is selected?

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Yaah can say that. Also, please let me know that if I have to disable the "Add New" button , when nothing is selected (including "first time page load" or multiple number of times) then where shall I put your code ? I mean inside which event ? And If item is selected then where shall I put the "else" condition ?? SO that all should work as per expected.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. when I place the code in `Page_Load()` event, I get this error : **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array**. At Line: **GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)RGGSTAcCode.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];** . Please reply how to solve it? This is the starting line of my code: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCompany.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)RGGSTAcCode.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];`

Comment: Okay, seems `Page_Load()` event is executed too early. Create `RadGrid_DataBound()` event and paste the code to disable the buttons in this event. Then the buttons will be disabled directly after the RadGrid has been databounded. And remove the code from `Page_Load()` event.

Comment: Ok when I put my code under `RadGrid_DataBound()` event, then its working fine on first time page load. But When I place my code under `RadComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged()` event as: `protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCompany.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            foreach (GridDataItem item in RGGSTAcCode.EditItems)
            {
                //Dropdown Bind logic
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Add New button disable logic
        }
    }`

Comment: Then its not going inside `foreach (GridDataItem item in RGGSTAcCode.EditItems)` statement. Due to this every time it goes inside "else condition" and my "Add New" button always remain disabled (no matter I am selecting items from RadComBox or not). Please suggest some solution. what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82903/discussion-between-roman-and-user3196511).

Comment: @user3196511, see my latest chat message

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I had solved the issue. I tried the same code suggested by you in your answer but on `RGGSTAcCode_ItemCommand` event. And its working fine as per my requirement. Thank you so much for the help. Please check the updated solution.